# Runtime Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: vba

I've seen numerous questions on the issue but none of the solutions fit my situation (I think) so any help is appreciated. I receive the error when setting the value of the **LR** integer variable. As with many others having this issue, it only fails the second time the subroutine is run.

```
Sub SaveEmailAttachments()
    ' Creates each variable to be used
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlWB As Excel.Workbook, xlAtt As Excel.Workbook
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim LR As Integer, NR As Integer, j As Integer, intDir As Integer, random As Integer
    ' Path to the HWB Master template to be used
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\SOF Station HWB Master w Macro.xlsm"

    ' If no emails are selected, present an error and exit
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Creates a new Excel application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application 
    xlApp.Visible = False

    'Opens the Excel workbook
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

    'Creates a new directory to store today's information
    intDir = (fIsFileDIR("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy"), vbDirectory))

    If intDir = 0 Then
        MkDir ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy"))
        MkDir ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & "\HWBs")

        'Process each selected email
        For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
            j = j + 1
            For cnt = 1 To olItem.Attachments.Count
                If Right(olItem.Attachments(1).FileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(olItem.Attachments(1).FileName, 3) = "xls" Or Right(olItem.Attachments(1).FileName, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                    olItem.Attachments(cnt).SaveAsFile ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & "\HWBs\" _
                    & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & " " & j & olItem.Attachments(cnt).DisplayName)

                    Set xlAtt = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & "\HWBs\" _
                    & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & " " & j & olItem.Attachments(cnt).DisplayName)

                    xlAtt.Activate
                    If xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = "HWB" And xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value = "Instruction (optional)" And xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = "Route (optional)" Then
                        LR = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A4:C4" & LR).Select
                        Selection.Copy
                        xlWB.Activate
                        xlWB.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
                        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        xlWB.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate
                    End If

                    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
                    xlAtt.Close SaveChanges:=False
                Else
                    olItem.Categories = "Purple Category"
                End If
            Next
        Next olItem

        j = 4
        LR = xlWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Do Until j > LR
            If IsNumeric(Cells(j, 1)) = False Then
                Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                LR = LR - 1
            ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then
                Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                LR = LR - 1
            Else
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Loop
        xlWB.SaveAs ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & "\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & " Complete HWB List")
    Else
        ans = MsgBox("You have already run SOF today, would you like to continue anyway?", vbYesNo)
        If ans = vbYes Then
            random = Int((9999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
            MkDir ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & random)
            MkDir ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & random & "\HWBs")
            MsgBox "Your new folder is titled " & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & random & ", it is located in the Documents\SOF\HWB Files directory"
            'Process each selected email
            For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
                j = j + 1
                For cnt = 1 To olItem.Attachments.Count
                    If Right(olItem.Attachments(1).FileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(olItem.Attachments(1).FileName, 3) = "xls" Or Right(olItem.Attachments(1).FileName, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                        olItem.Attachments(cnt).SaveAsFile ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & random & "\HWBs\" _
                        & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & " " & j & olItem.Attachments(cnt).DisplayName)

                        Set xlAtt = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & random & "\HWBs\" _
                        & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & " " & j & olItem.Attachments(cnt).DisplayName)

                        xlAtt.Activate
                        If xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = "HWB" And xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value = "Instruction (optional)" And xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = "Route (optional)" Then
                            LR = xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            xlAtt.ActiveSheet.Range("A4:C4" & LR).Select
                            Selection.Copy
                            xlWB.Activate
                            xlWB.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            xlWB.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate
                        End If
                        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
                        xlAtt.Close SaveChanges:=False
                    Else 
                        olItem.Categories = "Purple Category"
                    End If
                Next
            Next olItem

            j = 4
            LR = xlWB.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Do Until j > LR
                If IsNumeric(Cells(j, 1)) = False Then
                    Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    LR = LR - 1
                ElseIf Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then
                    Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                    LR = LR - 1
                Else
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Loop

            xlWB.SaveAs ("C:\Users\dkirksey\Documents\SOF\HWB Files\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & random & "\" & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & " Complete HWB List")
        Else
            xlWB.Close
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
            xlApp.Quit
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    xlWB.Close
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlApp.Quit

    MsgBox "Well played !"
End Sub
```

I'm a rookie with VBA so excuse any redundant or just plain idiotic coding methods you notice.
The subroutine works perfectly the first time it is run, just not the second. Please help.

Thank you.